# getting errors.. Using Socket in python

Tags: python, sockets

This is the task:

> Your task is to write a Python program that should test the given host and it should generate a list of all the TCP Open ports within the range of 1 to 1025. You are required to accomplish this task by using standard Python’s “socket” library. Following are the functional requirements:
>
> 1. On execution of program system should prompt “Enter a host to scan”. User will provide a host name
> 2. System should look for all the ports between the range of 1 to 1025
> 3. If the Ports is open it should create a file and add an entry for port number
> 4. In case of any exception for instance “host is not available”, “host name could not be resolved” or due to any other error you need to write that exception into same file
> 5. You also need to record starting and ending date and time at the beginning and ending of file accordingly. It should also show the total time it took in port scanning process.

This is the source code that I wrote with the help of online resources (also attaching screenshots of code):

```py
import socket
#Syntax for creating a socket
sock = socket.socket (socket_family, socket_type)

#Creates a stream socket
sock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#AF_INET 
#Socket Family (here Address Family version 4 or IPv4) 

#SOCK_STREAM Socket type TCP connections 

#SOCK_DGRAM Socket type UDP connections 

#Translate a host name to IPv4 address format 
gethostbyname("host") 

#Translate a host name to IPv4 address format, extended interface
socket.gethostbyname_ex("host")  

#Get the fqdn (fully qualified domain name)
socket.getfqdn("8.8.8.8")  

#Returns the hostname of the machine..
socket.gethostname()  

#Exception handling
socket.error



#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
from datetime import datetime

# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

# Ask for input
remoteServer    = raw_input("Enter a remote host to scan: ")
remoteServerIP  = socket.gethostbyname(remoteServer)

# Prints a banner with information on which host we are about to scan
print ("-" * 60)
print ("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
print ("-" * 60)

# Check what time the scan started
t1 = datetime.now()

# Using the range function to specify ports (here it will scans all ports between 1 and 1024)

# We also put in some error handling for catching errors

try:
    for port in range(1,1025):  
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print ("Port {}:      Open".format(port))
        sock.close()
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("You pressed Ctrl+C")
    sys.exit()

except socket.gaierror:
    print ('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
    sys.exit()

except socket.error:
    print ("Couldn't connect to server")
    sys.exit()

# Checking the time again
t2 = datetime.now()

# Calculates the difference of time, to see how long it took to run the script
total =  t2 - t1

# Printing the information to screen
print ('Scanning Completed in: ', total)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Uday\Desktop\Tempo\socket project.py", line 3, in <module>
    sock = socket.socket (socket_family, socket_type)
NameError: name 'socket_family' is not defined
>>>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This line was probably meant to be a comment, there should be a `#` at the start of the line.

Comment: `sock = socket.socket (socket_family, socket_type)`. The variables `socket_family` and `socket_type` are NOT defined.

Comment: @JuanR how do I fix that? ... actually I'm just a beginner and a school student so don't know much..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site, NOT a debugging service, and NOT a homework service. Please take the [tour] and read the [help], especially [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/) You are expected to do your own work, and ask *specific* questions as needed.  "Do this for me" requests are not what this site is meant for.

Comment: @Uday "*how do I fix that?*" - Juan told you exactly how to solve it. Comment out (put a `#` in front of) the 3rd line of code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did that but it's generating another error in line 14

Comment: @Uday What is the actual error? In the code you provided, line 14 is a blank line, there is nothing on it. Have you been making more changes that affect the formatting of the code? In any case, your use of `gethostbyname()`, `socket.gethostbyname_ex()`, `socket.getfqdn()`, `socket.gethostname()`, and `socket.error` are all wrong.  Also, the code you provided looks like it is actually 2 files merged together, is that really the case?

Comment: @RemyLebeau
sorry its the 16th line
here's the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Uday\Desktop\Tempo\socket project.py", line 16, in <module>     gethostbyname("host") NameError: name 'gethostbyname' is not defined >>> `

Comment: @Uday see my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72777697/getting-errors-using-socket-in-python?noredirect=1#comment128549231_72777776) about that error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yea this could be the case as I mentioned in my Question that I wrote this with the help of online sources because im just a beginner in python and using socket library for the first time.... however, what should I do now?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I prepended it & what values should I put into those and where should `socket.error` be added ...
and for your kind information this is not a homework question. currently im learning python so I just wanted to practice some libraries so I came across this question/ scenario to Solve & Learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the third line in your code is the problem, you should comment it out with a #

Comment: hey thanks for answering!
I commented the third line with #
but now im getting another error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Uday\Desktop\Tempo\socket project.py", line 16, in <module>
    gethostbyname("host")
NameError: name 'gethostbyname' is not defined
>>> `

how do i solve this... i might be annoying... but im new to this

Comment: @Uday `gethostbyname()` is part of the `socket` module, you can't call it as a standalone function like you are trying to.  Prepend it with `socket.` like you are with the other function calls, eg: `socket.gethostbyname("host")`. Also, you are ignoring the return values of `gethostbyname()`, `gethostbyname_ex()`, `getfqdn()`, and `gethostname()`. And you are using `socket.error` where it doesn't belong.  Seems to me that you need to learn some *fundamental* Python skills before you tackle sockets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Uday Again, if you look at the error you are getting is telling you that you are using an undefined function, be it because gethostbyname is part of a class that you forgot to add to it like Remy is telling you above or because you put it in as an aid and forgot to comment it out... You are not annoying, programming can be annoying, I don't really know that much, but I'm starting and you and I have a lot of headtowall banging to do...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify values for those 2 parameters when creating your `socket.socket`

By looking at the rest of your source code you would want to use `socket.AF_INET` for your socket_family and `socket.SOCK_STREAM` for socket_type. This tells the system to open a "TCP" socket using the "IPv4" address family.

Since you already have that in the line below, my simplest explanation would be that you just forgot to place the comment expression `#` in that line ;)